# how to set shared Preference for Login through Phone OTP android studio using java

Tags: java, android, firebase

I just created an app where a user can log in through phone OTP but I need to set shared Preference to check whether the user is registered or not. and please one more, Where to write that code. FIREBASE DATABASE. I wrote some code please check out
in the main activity, there is only entering the number and by putting number I called verifyPhonenumber class which given below

```
**THis verifyPhone number activity after putting  number user phone number will verify here**
public class VarifyPhoneNumber extends AppCompatActivity {

        //These are the objects needed
        //It is the verification id that will be sent to the user
        private String mVerificationId;

        //The edittext to input the code
        private EditText editTextCode;

        //firebase auth object
        private FirebaseAuth mAuth;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_varify_phone_number);

            //initializing objects
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            editTextCode = findViewById(R.id.editTextCode);


            //getting mobile number from the previous activity
            //and sending the verification code to the number
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String mobile = intent.getStringExtra("mobile");
            sendVerificationCode(mobile);
         


            //if the automatic sms detection did not work, user can also enter the code manually
            //so adding a click listener to the button
            findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String code = editTextCode.getText().toString().trim();
                    if (code.isEmpty() || code.length() < 6) {
                        editTextCode.setError("Enter valid code");
                        editTextCode.requestFocus();
                        return;
                    }

                    //verifying the code entered manually
                    verifyVerificationCode(code);
                }
            });

        }


        private void sendVerificationCode(String mobile) {
            PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber( "+92" +  mobile, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                    TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD,
                    mCallbacks);
        }


        //the callback to detect the verification status
        private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {

                //Getting the code sent by SMS
                String code = phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();

                //sometime the code is not detected automatically
                //in this case the code will be null
                //so user has to manually enter the code
                if (code != null) {
                    editTextCode.setText(code);
                    //verifying the code
                    verifyVerificationCode(code);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
                Toast.makeText(VarifyPhoneNumber.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);

                //storing the verification id that is sent to the user
                mVerificationId = s;
            }
        };


        private void verifyVerificationCode(String code) {
            //creating the credential
            PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(mVerificationId, code);

            //signing the user
            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
        }

        private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
            mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(VarifyPhoneNumber.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                               Toast.makeText(VarifyPhoneNumber.this, "Verified", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                //verification successful we will start the profile activity
                                FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                                FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
                                    @SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
                                    @Override
                                    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                                        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                                        if (firebaseUser != null) {
                                            String userId = firebaseUser.getUid();

                                            SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_UID" , Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                            sp.edit().putInt("Save_UID", Integer.parseInt(userId));
                                            sp.edit().apply();
                                        }
                                    }
                                };
                                Intent intent = new Intent(VarifyPhoneNumber.this, Profile.class);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            } else {

                                Toast.makeText(VarifyPhoneNumber.this, "not Verified", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                                verification unsuccessful.. display an error message

                                String message = "Somthing is wrong, we will fix it soon...";

                                if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                                    message = "Invalid code entered...";
                                }

                                final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.parent), message, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                                snackbar.setAction("Dismiss", new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                    Snackbar snackbar1=snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.parent),"UNDO Successful",snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                    snackbar1.show();

                                    }
                                });
                                snackbar.show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }

    }



**And this SplashScreen where I want to check whether the user is registered or not **
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
        Thread thread=new Thread(){
           public void run(){
              try {
                  sleep(4000);
              }
              catch (Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace();
              }
              finally {
                  SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_UID", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                  int sc  = sp.getInt("Save_UID",0);
                  if (sc!=0){
                      Intent intent=new Intent(SplashScreen.this, Profile.class);
                      startActivity(intent);
                      finish();
                  }
                  else {
                      Intent intent=new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                      startActivity(intent);
                      finish();
                  }
                }
           }

        };thread.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: They way you set it is already correct. Have you tried running the code? If so, any error messages or diagnostic messages would be incredibly helpful. Also, if you could elaborate on what you're trying to achieve, that would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add value to sharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("data", 0);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                        editor.putString("user_id", value to be set);
                        editor.apply();
```

And you can accesss the data inside the SharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("data", "0");
UserId = sharedPreferences.getString("user_id", "");
```

it will return the value of user_id . if the value is null it will return the empty string ""

Comment: Whether I should mention the if-else case to check stored preferences? in splash screen or after varifying number check from the mentioned code.